# $this->load->library('form_helper') equivalent in C++?

Tags: php, c++, oop, codeigniter, this

I am wondering if you were to write the following Codeigniter PHP code:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

In C++

would it be something like this

```
class CI {}; //class

CI this; //instance of class made called this

this.load.library('form_validation');
```

This is purely academic and not for practical purposes.

As I am trying to make an equivelant to CI in C++ for fun

Thanks

Comment: From the [faq]: "You should only ask **practical**, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. "

Comment: `this` is a keyword, you can't use it as a name. And for those of us that don't know PHP, what is it that you're trying to *do*?

Comment: well im trying to understand codeigniter by making a copy of it in PHP

Comment: @mat how do you know there is no practical merits to this question. Understanding OOP accross different programming languages by finding equivalances is very importan!

Comment: You state yourself that this is "not for practical purposes". How should I interpret that? Understanding programming languages, whatever their paradigm(s) is indeed very important, but posting theoretical, "what if" questions is not on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just so much wrong with this question.

C++ is a compiled language vs PHP which is interpreted.

In C++ one has to include references to libraries using the `#include` statement. This effectively implants the source of that file into the file being used.

The codeigniter example is loading its own library code since its a framework.

This could be accomplished in C++ by writing one's own framework and libraries.

Codeigniter is basically parsing the library at runtime to add functionality.

The same could be done by writing a server wrapper with functionality to import C++ code when passed a library argument.

Answer (score 1):

No-- Loading a library in C++ is platform-specific and not very simple.

C++ is a very different language than PHP, and if you are unfamiliar with it, you should try a much simpler project first...

Comment: ok thanks so are you saying it would have to be done through header files loaded into a base class?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

in this statement, $this is a keyword refering to the class you are currently in, meaning if you are in a method of class Foo, then $this refers to the the Foo object.

"->" is similar to a dot "." in c++, separating an object reference from its properties or methods, meaning if object $foo has a method named bar(), $foo->bar() would call that method.

"load" and "library" are both object and method names that are specific to the codeigniter controller base class, and are therfore meaningless in c++ unless you create them yourself.

Comment: so how would you bring in other classes to a base class in C++? Loading through header files

Comment: i imagine you would set a property of the base class to be an object. object.property = otherobject.

Comment: @sqlmole: "how would you bring in other classes to a base class in C++" This doesn't make sense. What does it mean to load "other classes to a base class"?

Comment: @GMan i think he means setting a property of an object to be another object.

Comment: Well in Codeigniter you have your base class, and then you load any other classes through the base class, from my understand. Then you just use the instance from the base class which contains all the methods from the base class and any loaded classes.

Comment: @sqlmole: Google for "C++ plugin architecture", you'll find what I think you want. Here's the deal: if you want to program something in C++, you can't keep talking in terms of PHP or some other framework. You need to extract from it what it is you want to do in language-agnostic terms, then reapply it to whatever language it is you want. You want to work with plugins, so you should be asking "how can I use plugins in C++?" not "How can I do PHP thing XYZ?"

Comment: @sqlmole you would most likely set properties to be certain objects in the base classes constructor method, then all classes that extend this base class would have the same constructor. constructors are the method that is run when someone instantiates an object from the class.